# iCarousel data source issue

Tags: ios, icarousel

I started to use `iCarousel` but got this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIView 0x8372530> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key dataSource.'
```

1. I have added QuartzCore framework
2. Copied iCarousel to my project
3. Copied XIB from the example

I have used this example [iCarousel](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/create-an-awesome-carousel-version-2-0/?search_index=2)

My code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "iCarousel.h"

@interface UsersViewController : UIViewController <iCarouselDataSource, iCarouselDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet iCarousel *aCarousel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL wrap;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *animals;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *descriptions;

- (IBAction)onTapBackButton:(id)sender;

@end




#import "UsersViewController.h"

@interface UsersViewController ()

@end

@implementation UsersViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        _wrap = NO;

        self.animals = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Bear.png",
                        @"Zebra.png",
                        @"Tiger.png",
                        @"Goat.png",
                        @"Birds.png",
                        @"Giraffe.png",
                        @"Chimp.png",
                        nil];

        self.descriptions = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Bears Eat: Honey",
                             @"Zebras Eat: Grass",
                             @"Tigers Eat: Meat",
                             @"Goats Eat: Weeds",
                             @"Birds Eat: Seeds",
                             @"Giraffes Eat: Trees",
                             @"Chimps Eat: Bananas",
                             nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.aCarousel.type = iCarouselTypeCoverFlow2;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark - Main Actions

- (IBAction)onTapBackButton:(id)sender
{
    [self dissmis];
}


#pragma mark - Main methods

- (void)dissmis
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma - mark iCarousel Delegate

- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    return [self.animals count];
}

- (NSUInteger)numberOfVisibleItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    // limit the number of item views loaded concurrently (for performance)
    return 7;
}

- (UIView*)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    // create a numbered view
    view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[self.animals objectAtIndex:index]]];
    return view;
}

- (NSUInteger)numberOfPlaceholdersInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    return 0;
}

- (CGFloat)carouselItemWidth:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    // usually this should be slightly wider than the item views
    return 240;
}

- (BOOL)carouselShouldWrap:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    return self.wrap;
}

- (void)carouselDidScroll:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    [self.label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.descriptions objectAtIndex:carousel.currentItemIndex]]];
}

@end
```

Comment: Where are you setting the delegate and data source for the carousel?

Comment: @Wain I am setting them in XIB drag to File's Owner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know exactly what the issue is, but after looking at a couple other posts, heres the top 5 I think may be the issue, hope it helps, good luck broski

1.

> I've found the most common place this error happens is when you
>   instantiate a view from a xib from within a class that is not the
>   xib's owner.
>
> What I mean by this is you might be calling something similar to this:
>
> [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:self options:nil];
>   You're changing the owner, so you have to be sure that the class that
>   self refers to has all the IBOutlet properties needed by "MyView".
>   Usually this is done in Interface Builder, but in this case you're
>   setting your owner programmatically, which means you can't make the
>   connections in IB. When the IBOutlets aren't there, the app tries to
>   make those connections and fails, giving the error you see.
>
> My advice (without knowing any more info than you've given so far) is
>   to check to see if you've made this call without having the proper
>   IBOutlets.

2.

> I had connected an UIControl outlet in the interface builder to the
>   IBOutlet in the xib's owner. For some reason, the IBOutlet was deleted
>   from the owner, but the reference to the outlet remained dangling in
>   the xib. This would always give me the error Lesson learnt: When
>   deleting any outlets for vars in the implementation, make sure to
>   unhook the respective connection in the IB

3.

> I found the problem, it was because of a button i used in the
>   AboutViewController, i didnt declare the property for that button.

4.

> Also when you rename a view, don't forget to delete the reference on
>   File's Owner. It may also raise this error.

5.

> Fixed - went to iOS Simulator > Reset Content and Setting

Comment: very helpful instruction, but in my case it does not work. but some programmers can use it in cases when they are faced with unexpected issues. +1 Jason G